# Next JS conditional image rendering

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I'm trying to have restaurant cards displayed on my app and I'm not sure what would be the best way to have the image conditionally render according to which restaurant it is. This way it works but it is not optimal since if I have 10 I have to manually add all 10 imports and cases.

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import styles from "../styles/Card.module.css";
import kegLogo from "../assets/Keg.png";
import Image from "next/image";
import pizzaLogo from "../assets/pizza-logo.png";

function RestaurantCard({ id, title, description }) {
  return (
    <Link className={styles.link} href={`/restaurants/${title}`}>
      <div className={styles.card}>
        {id == 1 && (
          <Image className={styles.image} src={kegLogo} alt={title} />
        )}
        {id == 2 && (
          <Image className={styles.image} src={pizzaLogo} alt={title} />
        )}
        <div className={styles.content}>
          <h3 className={styles.title}>{title}</h3>
          <p className={styles.description}>{description}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

export default RestaurantCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use object at your child component which received props, and use title or id as keys for your object pair

```
const imageObj = {
 title1: image1,
 title2: image2,
}
```

so your Image component would be

```
<Image className={styles.image} src={imageObj[title]} alt={title} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Like id, title, and description, imageSrc can be passed as a prop. As a result, the component is not needed to keep logic within itself.